# Download the necessary .properties file depending on the OS

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties

There are two configuration files for different OS `windows.properties` and `unix.properties`.

There is a configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties (prefix = "storage")
public class StorageProperties {

     private String root;
     private String sitesDirName;
     private String avatarsDirName;
     private String screenshotsDirName;

     @PostConstruct
     public void postConstruct () {

     }

}
```

How to make so that a certain file would be loaded depending on the OS? I ran across `@Conditional`, but this is one condition. Maybe he will help somehow.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Define an enum for OS .Use system property `os.name`  to determine current OS :

```
public enum OS {
    WINDOWS, UNIX, MAC, UNKNOWN;

    public static OS currentOS() {
        String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

        if (OS.indexOf("win") >= 0) {
            return WINDOWS;
        } else if (OS.indexOf("nix") >= 0 || OS.indexOf("nux") >= 0 || OS.indexOf("aix") > 0) {
            return UNIX;
        } else if ((OS.indexOf("mac") >= 0)) {
            return MAC;
        } else {
            return UNKNOWN;
        }
    }
}
```

(2) Implement `ConditionalOnOS` :

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Conditional(OsCondition.class)
public @interface ConditionalOnOS {
    OS os();
}

public class OsCondition implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {

        MultiValueMap<String, Object> attrs = metadata.getAllAnnotationAttributes(ConditionalOnOS.class.getName());
        if (attrs != null) {
            Object os = attrs.getFirst("os");
            if (os != null && os instanceof OS) {
                if (OS.currentOS().equals(((OS) os))) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

(3) Configure `@ConfigurationProperties` for different OS. Use `@PropertySource` to define the properties file paths for different OS:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "storage")
public static class StorageProperties {
    private String root;
    private String sitesDirName;
    private String avatarsDirName;
    private String screenshotsDirName;

    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("classpath:windows.properties")
    @ConditionalOnOS(os = OS.WINDOWS)
    public static class WindowsStrogeProperties extends StorageProperties {

    }

    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("classpath:unix.properties")
    @ConditionalOnOS(os = OS.UNIX)
    public static class UnixStrogeProperties extends StorageProperties {

    }
}
```

(4) Inject `StorageProperties` to the client

Answer (score 0):

`@Conditional` would be useful to determine the operating system, whereby you would have to define the conditional classes.

As a shorter approach, you can use good old if statements to determine the operating system. Assuming you have two different files, `windows.properties` and `unix.properties` as suggested, create the configuration class to determine the operating system and load the appropriate `.properties` file.

The code for the configuration class is as shown below.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import com.sun.javafx.PlatformUtil;

@Configuration
public class OSConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
                String osName = "";

    if (PlatformUtil.isWindows()) {
        osName = "windows";
    } else if (PlatformUtil.isUnix()) {
        osName = "unix";
    } else if (PlatformUtil.isMac()) {
        osName = "mac";
    }

    String propertiesFilename = osName + ".properties";
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    configurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource(propertiesFilename));

    return configurer;
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure if you really want to rely on a JavaFX class for this, as this has been removed in newer Java versions. Also adding an additional `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` might cause issues and will not let the regular Spring Boot magic happen with property files.

Comment: Yes, @M.Deinum raises good points, especially on the JavaFX having been removed from newer Java versions.

As per Java release notes: [JavaFX is no longer included in the JDK. It is now available as a separate download from openjfx.io](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html)